# How to apply transform method to partial data frame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data frame with many columns. I want to apply `MinMaxScaler` in `from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler` to the data frame.

However, previously I merger two dataframes into one and added a column 'type' to differentiate. So 'type' column has two values 'train' and 'test'.

Now when I wanted to apply the scalar to it, it throws error saying the values should be numbers. I get that.

So I wrote the code like this:

```
scalar = MinMaxScaler()
data = pd.DataFrame(scalar.fit_transform(data), columns=data.columns.drop("type"))

data.head()
```

This means I give only the specified column for it right? But still I'm getting the same error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-216-85712d22d323> in <module>
      1 scalar = MinMaxScaler()
----> 2 data = pd.DataFrame(scalar.fit_transform(data), columns=data.columns.drop("type"))
      3 
      4 data.head()
      5 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'train'
```

All I want is to apply the transform to all the column except that specific "type" column. Is there a way to do that with Pandas? If not, what are the alternatives?

I'm new to these stuff so please explain your solutions a bit more.

Also I noticed all methods of sklearn are made to work with numpy and not pandas dataframe. Everything takes an array as argument rather than a dataframe. Is it possible to send in data frames as inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still applying the `MinMaxScaler` to the whole dataframe with
`scalar.fit_transform(data)`.

One way to cope with this issue would be to:

1. create a new dataframe `df` without the 'type' column
2. scale `df` with `MinMaxScaler` and wrap it in a pandas dataframe again
3. add the 'type' column of the original dataframe to `df`

Here is the corresponding code:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd


df = data.drop("type", axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df),
    columns=df.columns
)
df["type"] = data["type"]
```

Regarding your question about pandas dataframes as *input*, there is in general no problem. The `scikit-learn` API assumes [array-like](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-array-like) objects which include pandas dataframes. Notice however that the *return type* (also called *output*) is typically a numpy array, which might need to be taken care of (like in step 2 above).